# Separate a csv file based on common and uncommon dates from two separate csv files

Tags: r, csv

I have two csv files:

DAT1:

```
 Year,Month,Day,Rainfall
  1979,01,01,0.1
  1979,01,02,0.3
  1979,01,03,0.5
  1979,01,04,1
  1979,01,05,2
```

DAT2:

```
 SN,CY,Year,Month,Day,Hour,MSLP
 1,1979,1979,01,03,06,1000
 3,1979,1979,01,05,12,999
```

I want to

(1) extract the data with dates that are not common between DAT1 and DAT2.

(2) extract the data with common dates between DATA1 and DAT2 and add the "Rainfall" column.

So the expected output for (1) is:

```
Year,Month,Day,Rainfall
  1979,01,01,0.1
  1979,01,02,0.3
  1979,01,04,1
```

The expected output for (2) is:

```
 SN,CY,Year,Month,Day,Hour,MSLP,Rainfall
 1,1979,1979,01,03,06,1000,0.5
 3,1979,1979,01,05,12,999,2
```

The DAT1 has continuous dates from 1979-01-01 (daily), while DAT2 has random dates.

Right now, I am separating them manually! But I will be applying this for a data from 1979-2017.

Is there a more efficient on how to do this in R?

I'll appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest this `base R` approach using the data you shared as `a1` and `a2` (I also included it in the code):

```
#Data
a1 <- structure(list(Year = c(1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L), Month = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Day = 1:5, Rainfall = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 1, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
a2 <- structure(list(SN = c(1L, 3L), CY = c(1979L, 1979L), Year = c(1979L, 
1979L), Month = c(1L, 1L), Day = c(3L, 5L), Hour = c(6L, 12L), 
    MSLP = 1000:999, Rainfall = c(100L, 50L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Code:

```
#Code
a1[!paste(a1$Year,a1$Month,a1$Day) %in% paste(a2$Year,a2$Month,a2$Day),]
```

Output:

```
  Year Month Day Rainfall
1 1979     1   1      0.1
2 1979     1   2      0.3
4 1979     1   4      1.0
```

For second question you can use `merge()`:

```
merge(a2,a1,by.x=c('Year','Month','Day'),by.y=c('Year','Month','Day'),all.x=T,sort = F,suffixes = c('.1','.2'))
```

Output:

```
  Year Month Day SN   CY Hour MSLP Rainfall.1 Rainfall.2
1 1979     1   3  1 1979    6 1000        100        0.5
2 1979     1   5  3 1979   12  999         50        2.0
```

Comment: Apologies. I was still editing the question. There's another question but for the common dates.

Comment: @Lyndz Hi, I have added an update for second point you edited. Please check :)

Comment: great!! Thank you so much!